# Ajax call response time line showing 16041.2 days

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

My ajax call response time shows 16041.2 days in chrome developer console under network. I have no idea , why its showing these much days.

And I also want to know will this affect the page speed of my application?

Any solution for this issue will be appreciable.

Thank you.

I have added the screen shot

Comment: can you add a screenshot

Comment: There has been a similar question a few days ago. I can't find it at the moment but it's most surely a bug. EDIT: [Found it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20104908/chrome-network-web-developer-tool-tab-says-dojo-ajax-requests-are-taking-around) – The bug is already solved and will land shortly in Chrome stable.

Answer (score 0):

the result is the day difference between day passed and january 1,1970.this is because javascript takes jan 1 1970 as reference