# Chrome developer-tools receiving time is shown wrong

Tags: google-chrome, jquery, google-chrome-devtools

Main HTML page loads some more HTML contents per AJAX GET request:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  cache: false,
  dataType: 'html',
  url: 'other'
  ...
});
```

That 'other' page contains some HTML as well as a script tag with javascript only relevant for that 'other' page. E.g.:

```
<div class="other-stuff">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="foo.js"></script>
```

On the network tab in chrome developer tools receiving time for that "foo.js" script is shown to be "16042.4 days". Which roughly translates into 43.9 years. From the beginning of the unix epoch time?

Why could chrome fail to identify the starting time of the script download? Firefox developer tools measure time correctly.

[image: receiving time]
[image: headers]

Comment: see this answer  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20104908/chrome-network-web-developer-tool-tab-says-dojo-ajax-requests-are-taking-around

Comment: thanks bayoffire. I swear I used the search function before I posted my question

Answer (score 0):

As user @bayoffire suggested, this question was answered here:

[Chrome Network Web Developer Tool tab says Dojo AJAX requests are taking around 44 years to complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20104908/chrome-network-web-developer-tool-tab-says-dojo-ajax-requests-are-taking-around)

It's a google-chrome bug introduced in version `31.0.1650.57`. It was fixed as of version `31.0.1650.63`, or maybe even earlier one.